# Buffered/delayed ajax requests/keystrokes using JavaScript and JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httprequest, datatables

I am currently prototyping an enterprise web app which will include a quick search screen.
This screen uses JQuery and Datatables to provide a tabular view of the search results. Searches are performed based on matches to string entered in a text field. Each time a key is pressed, a new AJAX request is sent back to a servlet, the search is performed (across a large database) and results are returned via JSON to be updated on the table.

The search on the database is a costly operation. A lot of times when a user is typing, say, a name, they would type a number of letters in quick succession. This will result in multiple searches being triggered in the backend, sometimes unnecessarily.

I was wondering if there is a way of cleverly buffering those request. For example, if a user is typing "Jonathan", do not send a request for J, Jo, Jona, Jonath, ... if they are all typed within a time limit of each other, and only send the request when there is a sufficient gap in typing, i.e. when the letter n at the end is typed.

I know this will cost a slight delay but it may be a worthy compromise.

Do you think think this makes sense? Is there an existing pattern/library for such operations? Does it cause usability issues that I haven't thought of?

Greatly appreciate your opinions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case someone looking at a similar problem: after Spike's comment I checked datatables plugins and there's something that does exactly what I wanted above: see [fnSetFilteringDelay](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnSetFilteringDelay)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the jquery-ui framework's autocomplete function, which has a delay option that does exactly what you're looking for.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-delay

Comment: Thank you. After seeing that I realised I haven't checked if something similar is available in DataTables and ... yes there is! I'm going to give it a go now.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I hadn't even noticed that Datatables handled the filtering itself. Glad it pointed you in the right direction though!